# 404 Not Found при попытке получить get_headers (VK)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте, ув. пользователи!
Пытаюсь получить информацию об mp3 файле на сервере vk.com, но в ответ дает ошибку **HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found**

Код:

```
<?php
    $file_url = 'http://cs4883.userapi.com/u92342187/audios/15012c2aac27.mp3';
    $info  = get_headers($file_url,1);
    print_r($info);
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

P.S. не работает и при рабочей ссылке на файл.

Возвращает:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    [Server] => nginx/1.2.1
    [Date] => Thu, 08 Nov 2012 21:30:33 GMT
    [Content-Type] => text/html
    [Content-Length] => 403
    [Connection] => close
)
```

На денвере работает отлично..

---

**РЕШЕНО.**
Как просили:

```
<?php
/**
* Класс для работы с VK API
* Класс видоизменен. Первоначальный вид и ссылка на автора класса:
* http://a-panov.ru/2011/10/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-vkontakte-api-php/
*/
class vk {
    public static $error = '';

    /**
    * Основной метод для запроса данных
    *
    * @param $method string имя метода api
    * @param $method array дополнительные параметры api
    * @return array результат запроса или FALSE при ошибке
    */
    static function get($account = array(), $method, $params = array()) {
        if (empty($method)) {
            self::$error = 'Не задан метод';
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            // обнулить статус ошибки
            self::$error = '';
        }

        $params['api_id'] = $account['id_api'];
        $params['method'] = $method;
        // версия API
        if (empty($params['v'])) $params['v'] = '2.0';

        // упорядочить ключи по алфавиту
        ksort($params);

        // сформировать список значений вида key=value
        $datas      = array();
        $strdatas   = $account['user_id'];
        foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
            $strdatas .= $k . '=' . $v;
            $datas[]   = $k . '=' . urlencode($v);
        }

        // формирование подписи
        $sig = md5($strdatas . $account['key']);

        // полная строка запроса к API
        $url = 'http://api.vk.com/api.php' . '?' . implode('&', $datas) . '&sig=' . $sig;

        // получить результат
        $result = file_get_contents($url);

        if ($result) {
            // удалить ненужные символы
            $result = preg_replace('![\\x00-\\x1f]!', '', $result);

            // преобразовать json-строку в массив
            $arr = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

            // при наличии ошибка
            if (isset($arr['error'])) { // записать её текст
                self::$error = 'Ошибка: ' . $arr['error']['error_msg']
                    . ' (' . $arr['error']['error_code'] . ')';
                $arr         = FALSE;
            }
        } else {
            $arr         = FALSE;
            self::$error = 'Нет доступа к адресу ' . 'http://api.vk.com/api.php';
        }

        return $arr;
    }
}

/**
 * Настройки приложения
 */
$key_app = 'kjlsdhglsdhg'; // Ключ приложения
$user_id = 778787878; // Ид создателя
$api_id = 454545454545; // ID приложения

$method = 'audio.getById'; // метод

/**
 * Получение информации
 */
$params = array();

$params['audios'] = '41589363_104634384';
$params['test_mode'] = 1;

$mp3 = vk::get(array(
    'key'       =>  $key_app, 
    'user_id'   =>  $user_id, 
    'id_api'    =>  $api_id),  $method, $params);

if (FALSE === $mp3) {
    exit ('Error');
} else {
    /**
     * Получаем заголовки файла
     */
    $get = get_headers($mp3->audio->url, 1);

    print_r($get);
}
```

Comment: Искал автора, только нашел ссылку.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для каждого пользователя ссылка на файл является уникальной. Прежде, чем получить ссылку, вы должны представится системе. 
Естественно, браузер и php это разные пользователи. Либо вы должны имитировать через headers/curl браузер.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.
Можно это выполнить и с помощью API VK, правильно?

Comment: Да, но тут серверная часть отодвигается на второй план, т.к. все запросы будут выполнятся так: клиент<->VK. Клиентом служит браузер, в роли "исполнителя команд" JavaScript. АПИ по сути не сложное, но с доками пришлось повозиться.

Comment: Я использую API без javascript, т.е. подключение к приложению vk.
Вот такая схема должна работать: коннектимся к вк приложению > посылаем запрос методом audio.getById и получаем ссылку > получаем информацию о файле

Comment: Хм, интересно! Было бы неплохо, если бы Вы написали работающий пример и обновили пост. Глядишь, кому-нибудь точно пригодится.

Comment: Хорошо =) Доделаю и выложу в пост.

Comment: Извините, что так долго)

Comment: Было бы неплохо и источник указывать, если вы взяли где-то в просторах интернетах :) А так-неплохо.

Answer (score 0):

подобная ссылка в контакте одноразовая, откройте это в броузере и убедитесь сами

Comment: Я написал в вопросе "P.S. не работает и при рабочей ссылке на файл."